# Cpanel Internal Server Error for wordpress

Tags: wordpress, cpanel

I have zipped my wordpress website built in my localhost and unzipped it on my capnel folder.
i.e http://example.com/foldername (cpanel file manager says "public_html/foldername")
Then i edit the wp-config.php with the DB_name and DB_user and password.
I uploaded the mysql database from cpanel->phpmyadmin

Now the problem in 500 internal server error.
I i couldn't resolve it.
Can anyone tell me if i need to change or add anything so that it works?
Please

Thanks
Rahul

Comment: often it is because of some error in the php file, mainly theme file. try first with the default theme. or it maybe because of db cofig. Not sure without any more infromation

Answer (score 0):

Just check your .htaccess files. Even small mistakes there will throw 500 error. Maybe before uploading your site you were using it for other sites which were misconfigured. Maybe there are indefinite internal redirects or something like that....

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

try use default .htaccess file ?

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

I was also having the same issue.
This is how i resolved.

- Delete `config.php` file.
- After importing database, go to `options` table.
- Find `siteurl` and `home`.
- Change their values to your new uploaded wordpress directory.
- Start wordpress again.
- It will start installing. Follow those steps.